# Change the functionality of wordpress users module in admin

Tags: wordpress, role

I want to restrict wordpress admin to view all users in user list.

For say, I have created custom roles (company users, employee). A company user type role can have multiple employees.

I want wordpress admin to only view company users.

I got, `args` in    `function prepare_items()`  inside  `WP_Users_List_Table` class can filter this. So have tried to override this in my theme's functions.php.

```
function my_prepare_items(){

    //my custom code goes here

}
add_action( 'prepare_items', 'my_prepare_items' );
```

But it's not working. How and where I can override this functionality without touching core wordpress methods?

EDIT :
This I want in admin UI.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can we see what you tried in functions.php?

Comment: @bsoist edited the question please check

Comment: prepare_items is not a hook, it's a class method intended to be overwritten in a child class. My suspicion is that you can avoid this. What are you trying to do? Filter which users are visible for an admin based on role?

Comment: @bsoist how to apply filter by default

Comment: you create a child class and implement `prepare_items()`